# failed to compile opus on android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, clang, opus

I would like to compile opus on android for one project.
I use a Android.mk to compile it.

It looks like that:

```
        ROOT := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOT)/opus-1.1
LOCAL_MODULE := libopus
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := celt/bands.c celt/celt.c celt/celt_decoder.c celt/celt_lpc.c celt/cwrs.c \
               celt/entcode.c celt/entdec.c celt/entenc.c celt/kiss_fft.c \
           celt/laplace.c celt/mathops.c celt/mdct.c celt/modes.c \
           celt/pitch.c celt/quant_bands.c celt/rate.c celt/vq.c \
           silk/A2NLSF.c silk/ana_filt_bank_1.c silk/biquad_alt.c \
           silk/bwexpander_32.c silk/bwexpander.c \
           silk/check_control_input.c silk/CNG.c silk/code_signs.c \
           silk/control_audio_bandwidth.c silk/control_codec.c \
           silk/control_SNR.c silk/debug.c silk/dec_API.c \
                   silk/decode_core.c silk/decode_frame.c silk/decode_indices.c \
                   silk/decode_parameters.c silk/decode_pitch.c \
           silk/decode_pulses.c silk/decoder_set_fs.c silk/enc_API.c \
           silk/encode_indices.c silk/encode_pulses.c silk/gain_quant.c \
           silk/HP_variable_cutoff.c silk/init_decoder.c \
           silk/init_encoder.c silk/inner_prod_aligned.c \
           silk/interpolate.c silk/lin2log.c silk/log2lin.c \
           silk/LPC_analysis_filter.c silk/LPC_inv_pred_gain.c \
           silk/LP_variable_cutoff.c silk/NLSF2A.c silk/NLSF_decode.c \
           silk/NLSF_del_dec_quant.c silk/NLSF_encode.c \
           silk/NLSF_stabilize.c silk/NLSF_unpack.c silk/NLSF_VQ.c \
           silk/NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c silk/NSQ.c silk/NSQ_del_dec.c \
           silk/pitch_est_tables.c silk/PLC.c silk/process_NLSFs.c \
           silk/quant_LTP_gains.c silk/resampler.c \
           silk/resampler_down2_3.c silk/resampler_down2.c \
           silk/resampler_private_AR2.c \
           silk/resampler_private_down_FIR.c \
           silk/resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c \
           silk/resampler_private_up2_HQ.c silk/resampler_rom.c \
           silk/shell_coder.c silk/sigm_Q15.c silk/sort.c \
           silk/stereo_decode_pred.c silk/stereo_encode_pred.c \
           silk/stereo_find_predictor.c silk/stereo_LR_to_MS.c \
           silk/stereo_MS_to_LR.c silk/stereo_quant_pred.c \
           silk/sum_sqr_shift.c silk/table_LSF_cos.c \
           silk/tables_gain.c silk/tables_LTP.c \
           silk/tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c silk/tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c \
           silk/tables_other.c silk/tables_pitch_lag.c \
           silk/tables_pulses_per_block.c silk/VAD.c silk/VQ_WMat_EC.c \
           silk/fixed/apply_sine_window_FIX.c silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c silk/fixed/corrMatrix_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/encode_frame_FIX.c silk/fixed/find_LPC_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/find_LTP_FIX.c silk/fixed/find_pitch_lags_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/find_pred_coefs_FIX.c silk/fixed/k2a_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/k2a_Q16_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/noise_shape_analysis_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/prefilter_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/process_gains_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/regularize_correlations_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/residual_energy16_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/residual_energy_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/schur64_FIX.c silk/fixed/schur_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/solve_LS_FIX.c \
           silk/fixed/vector_ops_FIX.c src/opus.c src/opus_compare.c \
           src/opus_decoder.c src/opus_encoder.c \
           src/opus_multistream.c src/repacketizer.c


LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/celt -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/silk/fixed -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -O3 -fno-math-errno
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(ROOT)
LOCAL_MODULE    := receiver-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := osl_receiver.c spsc_circular_queue.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -std=c99
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/opus-1.1/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lOpenSLES -llog -lz -lm
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libopus

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It's perfectly compile for mips64, mips, x86_64, x86, arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

But when gradle is trying to compile for armeabi, I have an issue.

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : opus <= NSQ_del_dec.c
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x314f020: i32 = ARMISD::SSAT 0x30e3a30, Constant:i32<15>
  0x30e3a30: i32 = sra 0x30e38e0, Constant:i32<1>
    0x30e38e0: i32 = add 0x30e0bd0, Constant:i32<1>
      0x30e0bd0: i32 = sra 0x3153cf0, Constant:i32<7>
        0x3153cf0: i32 = add 0x30b45e0, 0x30b1e50
          0x30b45e0: i32 = add 0x30e1110, 0x30e0fc0
            0x30e1110: i32 = sra 0x30b24e0, Constant:i32<16>
[...]
In function: silk_noise_shape_quantizer_del_dec
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
Android clang version 3.8.275480  (based on LLVM 3.8.275480)
Target: armv5te-none-linux-android
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/maathor/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************
PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/NSQ_del_dec-110b1d.c
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/NSQ_del_dec-110b1d.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************
make: *** [/home/maathor/app/smplayerapp/android/TestImport/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/opus/silk/NSQ_del_dec.o] Error 70
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/maathor/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/maathor/app/smplayerapp/android/TestImport/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_OUT=/home/maathor/app/smplayerapp/android/TestImport/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/maathor/app/smplayerapp/android/TestImport/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib /home/maathor/app/smplayerapp/android/TestImport/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi/libreceiver-jni.so}
  [armeabi] Compile thumb  : receiver-jni <= osl_receiver.c
```

Do you understand something ? I just would like to build it for my Samsung  Galaxy 5 on 6.0.1 !

Thanks for your reply !

**ANSWER:**

After many tests, it's perfectly work with NDK 13 B (the october 2016 version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, it's perfectly work with NDK 13 B (the october 2016 version)